# ELK Community Beats to gets AWS logs on ELK

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, kibana-6

I have my ELK server setup on Ubuntu 16.xx (AWS EC2 instance).
1 - I need to monitor my AWS services (SNS, SQS, SES, Lambda, Ec2, S3 ELB CloudWatch .. etc.)
2 - how can I get the real-time logs from my aws service and post to my Kibana   dashboard (is there any plugin/beat/integration api).
are there community beats can help me to get the logs from AWS to ELK.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/community-beats.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-cloudwatch.html

You probably want to use the Cloudwatch Logstash plugin and config it to pull that data into your elasticsearch, I believe is that is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below beats to retrieve cloudwatch logs and metrics.

**cloudwatchmetricbeat** - A beat for Amazon Web Services' CloudWatch Metrics.

**cloudwatchlogsbeat** - Reads log events from Amazon Web Services' CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. The above  CloudWatch beats  where i have to setup ? 
1 -on ELK server ( My ELK server is running on the Docker container)  ?
how can i setup ? there is an guide or steps to setup the beats and integrate it with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

A few more options to stream AWS logs to the ELK cluster are:

1) First push all your AWS logs to a S3 bucket and then use Logstash's "S3 input plugin" to stream logs from S3 to logstash.

2) Use a lambda function to stream all the cloudwatch logs directly to your ELK cluster. refer this: https://github.com/blueimp/aws-lambda/tree/master/cloudwatch-logs-to-elastic-cloud

Answer (score 0):

The Elastic Stack 6.5 has been released on Nov 14th and a new beat called [Functionbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-overview.html) allows you to stream your Cloudwatch logs easily to ES.